# Convert a dataframe to bytes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, base64

I have a dataframe in R , for ex

```html
Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4              
Male    12345    76     abc           
Female  545454   105    def
```

How can i convert  the data into a csv format (only the the cols and rows , no metadata) and then into bytes which i need to convert to a base64 encoded string and pass to a rest endpoint?

The base64 encoded string for this example should be

**`Q29sMSAgLCAgQ29sMiAgICwgQ29sMyAgLCBDb2w0ICAgICAgICAgICAgICANCk1hbGUgICwgMTIzNDUgICAsNzYgICAgICwgYWJjICAgICAgICAgDQpGZW1hbGUsIDU0NTQ1NCAgLDEwNSAgICAsIGRlZg==`**

So the data after decoding the base64 string will look like this:-

```
Col1  ,  Col2   , Col3  , Col4              
Male  , 12345   ,76     , abc           
Female, 545454  ,105    , def
```

I tried using serialize but that serializes everything including the metadata . i also tried writeBin but that only works on vectors

Any ideas?

Comment: Thoughts: `write.table(dat, stdout(), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)`; `?paste(capture.output(...), collapse='')`, `?caTools::base64encode`, and ensure that you have commas, spaces, etc, set *exactly* how you need them to look.

Comment: your solution works as i expect.....paste(capture.output(write.table(df, quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE , sep=",")), collapse="\n")...i was just wondering is there any performance hit if we use write.table for large dataframes ?

Comment: There's ***always*** consideration for performance. If you are going with larger datasets, why don't you just export to a file and use command-line base64 encoders? They will almost definitely work faster (depending on implementation), and simplify your *R* code.

Comment: "use command-line base64 encoders"-- i am not sure i fully understand this...i need to be able to send the base64Encoded string to a rest method  . ...How do i use the  command line encoders?  I can consider creating a new rest endpoint(the current endpoint uses "PUT" which accepts base64encoded csv formatted string), but are there any best practices on passing an R dataframe to a rest endpoint?

Comment: By "command-line base64 encoder" I mean something outside of *R*, perhaps found with `Sys.which("base64")` or `Sys.which("b64encode")`. If the answer you "checked" is enough, there's no need to complicate things here unless/until you run into problems (performance or otherwise).

Comment: yes definitely...both the solutions work..i am assuming both would perform appx the same same efficiency wise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the `RCurl` function for this?

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4              
                                     Male    12345    76     abc           
                                     Female  545454   105    def"), header=T)

header_row <- paste(names(df), collapse=", ")
tab <- apply(df, 1, function(x)paste(x, collapse=", "))
text <- paste(c(header_row, tab), collapse="\n")
> text
[1] "Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4\nMale,  12345,  76, abc\nFemale, 545454, 105, def"
x <- base64(text)
> x
[1] "Q29sMSwgQ29sMiwgQ29sMywgQ29sNApNYWxlLCAgMTIzNDUsICA3NiwgYWJjCkZlbWFsZSwgNTQ1NDU0LCAxMDUsIGRlZg=="
attr(,"class")
[1] "base64"
> base64Decode(x)
[1] "Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4\nMale,  12345,  76, abc\nFemale, 545454, 105, def"
```

Comment: Edited to add column names